# system calls in C

Tags: c, system

I have a function in C that calls another software to execute and generate a file then its manipulates the data e.g.

```
void main()
{
function();
//manipulate data in output.txt
}    
void execute()
{
system("./test input.txt output.txt");
}
```

for some reason the output.txt file is not being generated by full...how does the system call work? will execute return to main before system call ends? if yes how can I solve this? Im working on ubuntu using gcc

Comment: system should be waiting for the passed in command to finish. Perhaps an error is occuring in ./test? You can inspect the return value of system to check (though you'll have to consult the Ubuntu reference to see what values indicate what.)

Comment: Be aware that `./` means relative to the current working directory, not the directory containing your binary file.

Comment: it is also good to mention that when input.txt is small file it is working fine, but when input.txt is large it is like some data is not being processed....when I execute the code outside the code, it works properly so I thought it is from system call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check the result of system() ALWAYS.  Ensure that it executed successfully(ie. returns 0 or whatever is a successful result for 'test')
2. When system executes it runs through /bin/sh (on unix/linux anyway).  However since you're specifying it with './test' make sure that you're operating in the working directory that you THINK you are.  Complex systems(and poorly designed ones) change directories like underwear.

Comment: No kidding, found this in a piece of code in several places:   system("sleep 1") ;